# Random Service Worker Response Error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, service-worker

I'm using Service Worker  and Cache API to cache static resources but randomly http request to REST API endpoint (which is not being cached in SW) fails and the only message I have is `xhr.statusText` with text `Service Worker Response Error` and response code 500.

I can't tell if this error happens only with URLs that are not being cached or not. There is not enough evidence about either. This happens only in Chrome (50.0.2661.75 - 64b) and it works in Firefox 45

I wasn't able to reproduce it manually as it happens in Selenium tests and it appears to be random. Moreover it happens on localhost (where SW should work despite plain http) but also in domain with HTTPS that has self-signed certificate and as such SW should not even work there ...

Selenium tests are often refreshing pages and closing browser window but I have no idea if it matters.

Any ideas why it could be happening or how to get more information?

Update:
Service Worker code:

```
var VERSION = "sdlkhdfsdfu89q3473lja";
var CACHE_NAME = "cache" + VERSION;
var CACHE_PATTERN = /\.(js|html|css|png|gif|woff|ico)\?v=\S+?$/;

function fetchedFromNetwork(response, event) {
    var cacheCopy = response.clone();
    var url = event.request.url;
    if (url.indexOf("/api/") === -1 // must not be a REST API call
        && url.indexOf(VERSION) > -1 // only versioned requests
        && VERSION !== "$CACHE_VERSION"
        && CACHE_PATTERN.test(url)) { //
        caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
            .then(function add(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, cacheCopy);
                });
    }
    return response;
}

function unableToResolve() {
    return new Response("Service Unavailable", {
        status: 503,
        statusText: "Service Unavailable",
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        })
    });
}

this.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
    // cache GET only
    if (event.request.method !== "GET") {
        return;
    }

    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function (cached) {
            if (cached) {
                return cached;
            } else {
                return fetch(event.request)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return fetchedFromNetwork(response, event);
                        }, unableToResolve)
                        .catch(unableToResolve);
            }
        }, function () { // in case caches.match throws error, simply fetch the request from network and rather don't cache it this time
            return fetch(event.request);
        }));
});


this.addEventListener("activate", function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys()
        .then(function (keys) {
            return Promise.all(
                    keys.filter(function (key) {
                        // Filter out caches not matching current versioned name
                        return !key.startsWith(CACHE_NAME);
                    })
                    .map(function (key) {
                        // remove obsolete caches
                        return caches.delete(key);
                    }));
        }));
});
```

Comment: Interesting. Would be nice to have some code that reproduces the issue, even if it only fails for one run in a thousand.

Comment: I've added SW code that I'm using, it is hard to share more if I don't have any clue what could be the issue so it is difficult to isolate / create minimal setup

Comment: this comment might be interesting https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/content/browser/service_worker/service_worker_url_request_job.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=947&rcl=1464780037

Comment: Did you find solution? Im having same issue

Comment: Sadly no, I gave up on SW at that time due to this issue. Yesterday I've found this https://github.com/popeindustries/sw-tips , maybe following these tips would help. Honestly I hoped that this issue would be mitigated now as SW are more mature